# user invalid login

Tags: php

I am creating my own website just to get some experience. I've been working on it for 3 days and am at the point where I can sign up and sign in.

When signing in, if the combination of the username and password is not found in the database, my code displays an error message telling the user that either he didn't sign up yet or he is entering a wrong user email or password.

But, the message  is displayed in a new page, instead of the sign in page.

I looked at some tutorials online, but didn't find a good explanation for it. Could someone please give me some advise?

I am using PHP for the database connection.

Comment: Is the form action set to go to another page?

Comment: It would help us if you could show us your code.

Comment: please post ur code along with the question

Comment: its so hard to telling without your codes.. Please paste the code as well.

Answer (score 2):

I just typed a very basic example:

```
<?php
//login.php

$msg = '';  //to store error messages

//check whether the user is submitting a form
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')    //check if form being submitted via HTTP POST
{
    //validate the POST variables submitted (ie. username and password)

    //check the database for a match
    if($matchfound == TRUE) //if found
    {
        //assign session variables and other user datas

        //then redirect to the home page, since the user had successfully logged in
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = 'Error. No match found !';   //assign an error message

        include('login_html.php');  //include the html code(ie. to display the login form and other html tags)
    }
}
else    //if user has not submitted the form, just display the html form
{
    include('login_html.php');
}

//END of login.php
?>
```

login_html.php :

```
<html>
  <body>
<?php if(!empty($msg)) echo $msg; ?> <!-- Display error message if any -->
<form action="login.php" method="post">
  <input name = "username" type="text" />
  <input name = "password" type="password" />

  <input name = "submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not a complete code. But I just created it for you to understand how this can be done. :)

Good luck

Comment: Hi Akhilesh B Chandran, this code really helped to understand what is going on. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you. This is a very basic code and I didn't included the code for validation and other stuff. Make sure you include those.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Your opening form tag should look like this: `<form action="" method="post">`. The empty "action" attribute will cause the page to post back to itself. Just check the $_POST for username and password to determine whether to test for a match or just show the form.

And please be sure to hash your passwords and sanitize your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without going to a new page.

```
   <?php session_start(); ?>
   <?php

   if(isset($_POST) && isset ($_POST["admin_login"])){
        $user_data_row = null;
        $sql="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE <table_name.field name>='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'
            and <table_name.field name='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'
           ;
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $user_data_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if(is_array($user_data_row)){
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_data_row['id'];
            header("Location: <your page name>");
        }else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Valid email and password required";

        }
    }
 ?>



<?php if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
     echo "<li>{$message}</li>";

 ?>

 <form  action="" method="post"  id="customForm">
               <label>Email:</label>
               <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
               <label>Password:</label>
               <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="send" name="admin_login">
        </form>

    may be its helps you....
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically what you need to do, is post the form to the same page.

Once you have that, at the type just check for the $_POST: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

If it is a post, check the username and password and either show an error or redirect to the signed in page. After this, display the login form.

So, if it's an error, they'll get the error and then the login form. If it's not posted, they'll get just the login form, and if it's a valid login, they'll get redirected to the proper page before the login form is shown.

Comment: Cory Dee: I posted the forms to the same page, but it was still not working.